# Python: How to most effectively vectorize this for-loop (which uses pandas groupby)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying to create an aggregating stock function, looping over dates. Basically, I want to sum a variable based on a grouping, and iterating over dates.  I do have multiple entries for a given day, however, which complicates the problem slightly.  I'm currently using pandas.groupby, but this runs way too slow for my >3m rows, so I'm wondering how I could vectorize it instead.

Represented by some example code, I would like to vectorize the below. Imagine I am warehousing something, say, apples, for a set of customers, and I'd like to keep track of how many apples I am warehousing for each customer on any given day. Each customer can make a 'deposit' of some apples from one day to a date in the future, and can make several deposits each day.
The example code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'StartDate': ['2020-01-01','2020-01-01','2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-04','2020-01-05'],
      'EndDate':['2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-05','2020-01-05','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-06','2020-01-06','2020-01-06','2020-01-06'],
      'Apples':[5,6,2,4,4,10,8,9,3,7],
      'Customer':['A','B','A','C','A','A','B','B','C','A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)

cycledates = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-06']

def stockfunction(indata, ingroupingvars, cycledates):
    stock_agg = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in cycledates:
        stock_input = indata.loc[
            (indata['StartDate'] <= i) & (indata['EndDate'] > i)]
        stock_input['EvaluationDate'] = i
        stock_marg = stock_input.groupby(ingroupingvars)['Apples'].sum().unstack(level=0)
        stock_agg = stock_agg.append(stock_marg)
    return stock_agg

ingroupingvars = ['Customer','EvaluationDate']
stock = stockfunction(df,ingroupingvars,cycledates)
```

**Sample output**

The dataframe looks like this:

```
StartDate     EndDate  Apples Customer
0  2020-01-01  2020-01-02       5        A
1  2020-01-01  2020-01-02       6        B
2  2020-01-01  2020-01-05       2        A
3  2020-01-02  2020-01-05       4        C
4  2020-01-02  2020-01-03       4        A
5  2020-01-02  2020-01-04      10        A
6  2020-01-03  2020-01-06       8        B
7  2020-01-04  2020-01-06       9        B
8  2020-01-04  2020-01-06       3        C
9  2020-01-05  2020-01-06       7        A
```

And the end-result looks like this:

```
Customer         A     B    C
EvaluationDate               
2020-01-01       7   6.0  NaN
2020-01-02      16   NaN  4.0
2020-01-03      12   8.0  4.0
2020-01-04       2  17.0  7.0
2020-01-05       7  17.0  3.0
```

...it's just that it takes forever to run on my original data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to do a cross merge and query:

```
# convert to datetime type for safe comparison
Eval_df = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(cycledates, name='EvaluationDate')).to_frame()

df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])


(df.assign(dummy=1)
   .merge(cycledates.assign(dummy=1), on='dummy')
   .query('StartDate<=EvaluationDate<EndDate')
   .groupby(['EvaluationDate', 'Customer'])      # ingroupingvars
   ['Apples'].sum()                              #
   .unstack('Customer', fill_value=0)            # remove fill_value=0 if you want the NaN
)
```

Output:

```
Customer         A   B  C
EvaluationDate           
2020-01-01       7   6  0
2020-01-02      16   0  4
2020-01-03      12   8  4
2020-01-04       2  17  7
2020-01-05       7  17  3
```

Comment: Thanks @quang-hoang - I'll try this out.  I was a bit unspecific in my original heading of the question, though, can I just check whether this is 'properly' vectorizing, and not using pd.groupby, though?

Comment: what do you mean`*properly vectorized*? `pd.groupby` will try to vectorize the calcualtion. Plus, your problem is inherently `groupby`.

Comment: Thanks @quang-hoang for your suggested solution. I only made one small change to your code, replacing 'Eval_df' with 'cycledates'.

Your solution worked well on a very small sample of my data - but seems to be slower than the original when trying to use it on larger samples of the data.

Using <10% of original data, the old solution runs at 23.6s, while the new one is at 1m4s.  When running on larger sets of the data, I run out of memory (I have 16GB).

Comment: I've now been able to identify where this approach seems to be using memory:  it's seems to be from the .merge step, which makes the data set it needs to work with too large.  This because the storage of 'apples' in my original data set goes over many days, even up to 365, so each deposit is multiplied many times.  Using <5% of my original data set (c.100k rows), this was increased c.30 times to 3mn rows.   (And before running I also reduced the dataset removing superfluous columns, fro 66 to 5). Any further ideas or help hugely appreciated.